# Select query on multiple values from select list

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have a select list that I can get the user IDs via:

```
$('#lstUsers :selected').each(function(i, selected){ 
   console.log ($(selected).val());
});
```

I need to gather all of those values and then run a subsequent query such that

Select * from myTable where id = (id OR id2 OR id3... OR idN)

What's a good way to accomplish this?

Comment: use IN operator . will be faster , and will allow you to add all of your criterias separated by ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could do something like this:

```
var ids = [];
$('#lstUsers :selected').each(function(i, selected){ 
    ids = ids.concat($(selected).val());
});
var query = "Select * from myTable where id in (" + ids.join(",") + ")";
```

Answer (score 1):

Satya's comment is correct that IN is probably faster and makes it easier to generate the SQL.

But was your question more basic?  (Your js was not basic but the mysql question seems to be, so I'm not sure.) We're you asking how to query the server from a page running javascript?  If so, the answer is an [ajax call](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).  The URL will have a script that runs and calls requests the data (perhaps using `IN`) then outputs it (perhaps in JSON).  Your js receives it and does what it needs to with the returned data.